# how can i click a button when site is loaded

Tags: jquery

PHP :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

<?php

$uret = rand(300000,688255);

    echo 
    '<form action="albo.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="uret" value="'.$uret.'" />
    <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Gonder" /></div>

    </form>';

?>
```

click.JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click();
}
```

all im trying to do is click that submit button when a.php loads

Comment: pretty sure you cannot simulate clicks - for security reasons. You can call the click events that are registered though, with `$(this).click();`

Comment: @musefan: Clicking or triggering the click event is pretty much the same except when `window.open()` is involved (popup blocking)

Comment: i wrote this code in my click.js and called it in my php <script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script> but didnt work

Comment: 2 things. i suppose you included jquery somewhere since you are trying to use it. and click events need to be inside the $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: i tried $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click();
}  and i added jquery

Comment: @user1925151 button is an id here so you need to use a # instead of .

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

<?php

  $uret = rand(300000,688255);
 
    echo 
  '<form action="albo.php" method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="uret" value="'.$uret.'" />
  <div class="button"><input type="submit" value="Gonder" /></div>
  
  </form>';
  
  


?> this is my all php and  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click();
} this is my click.js file

Comment: @user1925151 can you update it in your post. and not in the comments makes reading abit easier

Comment: what do you want to happen when you click the button?

Comment: when a.php loaded , it will automatically click that submit button and then php will post that form input to albo.php thats all

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#button').click();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#button').click();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Reverse the order of adding `js` files, first load `jquery.js` after that `click.js`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user1925151 On which line?

Comment: @user1925151 before calling this `<script type="text/javascript" src="click.js"></script>` is `jquery.js` also called?

Comment: yes i called , $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click();
} this didnt work neither

Comment: error disappeared seems good but doesnt work when a.php loaded nothing happens

Comment: setinterval will execute multiple times, use setimeout.

Answer (score 0):

**Trigger**

```
$("#button input[type='submit']").trigger("click");
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/